# How can I use cjk path in \include command on windows?

Tags: windows, include, cjk

I want to use \input or \include command to include a file that name with cjk characters.

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\title{input with cjk path}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\input{中文}
\end{document}
```

and the 中文.tex is

```
hello, world
```

I have tried utf8 encoding, gbk encoding, but xelatex shows the same error

```
LaTeX Error: File `涓枃.tex' not found.
```

operating system is windows and I use xelatex command:

```
xelatex a.tex
```

and I have tried changed the code page, it still not working:

```
chcp 65001
xelatex a.tex
```

and a.log show

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX)(preloaded format=xelatex 2017.6.21)  3 JUL 2017 20:55
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**./a.tex
(./a.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
...
...
...
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 4.


LaTeX Warning: No \author given.


! LaTeX Error: File `中文.tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name: X

)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 5 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 5 was incomplete) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 19344 strings out of 493005
 406504 string characters out of 6131656
 441240 words of memory out of 5000000
 23197 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 6602 words of font info for 39 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 57i,6n,68p,10436b,270s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

No pages of output.
```

Comment: The file should be in UTF-8 encoding for xetex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I generate the `中文.tex` hello world file, and save the main file in UTF-8 it works for me with windows 10 (and texlive 2017 cygwin tex)

[image]

If I then re-save the main file in gbk encoding I get a file not found error
In my case I get

```
! LaTeX Error: File `����.tex' not found.
```

with all the characters being replaced by U+fffd "replacement character" rather than showing wrong characters as in your example, but the details of the utf-8 decoding may depend on the version of xetex that you have.

Comment: thanks for answer. the a.tex file's encoding is utf-8. and I use texlive without cygwin. I think the console showing wrong characters since my terminal's encoding is cp936, while the other name of gbk. and I chcp code page 65001, it can show the right characters. is there any way to use input with cjk path on windows without cygwin?

Comment: @txlg I think it should just work, (although I do not want to install a native windows texlive to check) there are plenty of windows users here who can check so leave the question open, and see who answers.  Rather than show the missing file message from the terminal which is affected by your terminal settings, can you show the message from the log (which should be in utf8 if the original input was utf8)

Comment: sorry for the log file. but the log file is to long, it over 1000 lines. so i only put the message I think usefull:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.6.21)  3 JUL 2017 20:55
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./a.tex
(./a.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
....
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 4.
LaTeX Warning: No \author given.
! LaTeX Error: File `中文.tex' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed

Comment: @txlg: I tried with the article class (to avoid font problems), and it works on windows 10 with miktex but not with texlive 2017.

Comment: @txlg so in the log it is `中文.tex` so basically I think you have done everything right, it just does not work in your implementation. see Ulrike's comment above.

Comment: @txlg If you want to keep with your existing xetex I thin you could use the sort name as shown by `dir /x` on my system I get `02/07/2017  18:02                11 F03A~1.TEX   中文.tex` so I think  `\input{F03A\string~1}` would work

Comment: thanks to David and Ulrike. I decide to use ProTEXt after trying cygwin yesterday(but not success). use the short name makes the article hard to read. so I didn't choose the solution.  I wish that texlive can fix the problem.

Comment: @txlg I guess I should report it....